# Error No Package called proxy in R programming

Tags: proxy

Am trying to excute the R code for Recommendation system on movie data set

when am running library(proxy) am getting error as there is no package called proxy

Am finding same error even after installing the package install.packages("proxy")

I got struck not going further.

Comment: Please post the error message appearing if that is possible.

Comment: > install.packages("proxy")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Rohit/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘proxy’ is not available (for R version 3.3.0)
> library(proxy)
Error in library(proxy) : there is no package called ‘proxy’

Comment: Update your [R version](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/) if possible, then the package will be working fine.